# How does one calculate the rate of change (derivative) of streaming data?

Tags: math, derivative

I have a stream of data that trends over time.  How do I determine the rate of change using  C#?

It's been a long time since calculus class, but now is the first time I actually need it (in 15 years).  Now when I search for the term 'derivatives' I get financial stuff, and other math things I don't think I really need.

Mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: This doesn't sound programming-related. It's not a well-specified problem in any case.

Comment: its programming related (how do i do X in C#), but the question would be better if it had a lot more information, like "i have these x values, or this array of floats and...".

Comment: More background on this problem is located here: [Ideas wanted for analyzing near-realtime data over specific intervals with memory/cpu efficiency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813556/ideas-wanted-for-analyzing-near-realtime-data-over-specific-intervals-with-memory "... lots of C# code there.")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want something more sophisticated that smooths the data, you should look into a a digital filter algorithm. It's not hard to implement if you can cut through the engineering jargon. The classic method is [Savitzky-Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter)

If you have the last `n` samples stored in an array `y` and each sample is equally spaced in time, then you can calculate the derivative using something like this:

```
deriv = 0
coefficient = (1,-8,0,8,-1)
N = 5 # points
h = 1 # second
for i range(0,N):
   deriv += y[i] * coefficient[i]
deriv /= (12 * h)
```

This example happens to be a N=5 filter of "3/4 (cubic/quartic)" filter. The bigger `N`, the more points it is averaging and the smoother it will be, but also the latency will be higher. You'll have to wait N/2 points to get the derivative at time "now".

For more coefficients, look here at the Appendix

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter

Answer (score 3):

You need both the data value `V` and the corresponding time `T`, at least for the latest data point and the one before that. The rate of change can then be approximated with [Eulers backward formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method#The_backward_Euler_method), which translates into

```
dvdt = (V_now - V_a_moment_ago) / (T_now - T_a_moment_ago);
```

in C#.

Comment: I don't like using a capital T for time (i'd rather have it lowercase), but it looked even worse with the "sub"-notes... Also, note that this is **not** the *exact* rate of change at the current moment - it's merely an *approximation*.

Comment: As long as it's close, that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Rate of change is calculated as follows

1. Calculate a delta such as "price minus - price 20 days ago"
2. Calculate rate of change such as "delta / price 99 days ago"

Answer (score 0):

Total rate of change, i.e. (new_value - original_value)/time?